# sql trim some leading 0

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm using an Oracle database, and need to trim some leading zeros, but I need to leave enough leading zeros to pad the field length to at least 4 characters. This is some sample data where 'myField' is the input and 'cooked' is what I want as the output:

```
myField     cooked
0000000009      0009
0000123456    123456
00ABCE1234  ABCE1234
```

I used this to accomplish my goal, but was wondering if there is a better way

```
case
  when length(trim(leading 0 from myfield)) >= 4 then trim(leading 0 from myfield)
  else lpad(trim(leading 0 from myfield), 4 , 0)
end as cooked
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is! For example, using `regexp_substr()`:

```
with
     test_data ( myfield ) as (
       select '0000000009' from dual union all
       select '0000123456' from dual union all
       select '00ABCE1234' from dual
     )
-- end of test data; solution (SQL query) begins below this line
select myfield, regexp_substr(myfield, '^0+(.{4,}$)', 1, 1, null, 1) as cooked
from   test_data
;

MYFIELD    COOKED   
---------- ----------
0000000009 0009      
0000123456 123456    
00ABCE1234 ABCE1234
```

This assumes `myfield` is at least four characters long; if it isn't, and you need to pad with zeros when it isn't, you could simply replace `myfield` with `'0000' || myfield`  in the function.